# Size constraints on CRISPR guide RNA

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, crispr

I had a quick questions on the size limitations of a CRISPR guide. More specifically on the shorter end. Can I make a guide that is say 7-10bp and still have an active complex? I transfect using an RNP system.

Just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely make such gRNA, but chances of off-targeting increases as you decrease the size of gRNA. It is always better to have 17-20 bp gRNA. However, you can check off-targets of a gRNA through several online tools.